# Multiple claim values when using LocalSTS from Identity and Access Tools

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wif

As part of our migration from VS 2010 to VS 2012 we have begun using the LocalSTS from Identity and Access Tools as STS during the development phase. It is very easy to setup but we do however encounter one problem and this is configuring it to include more than one claim value per claim type in the generated token. A typical configuration might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="localSTSConfiguration" type="System.IdentityModel.Tools.LocalSTS.LocalSTSConfiguration, LocalSTS, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <localSTSConfiguration port="13248" signingCertificate="LocalSTS.pfx" signingCertificatePassword="LocalSTS" issuerName="LocalSTS" tokenFormat="Saml11">
    <claims>
      <add type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" displayName="Name" value="Terry" />
      <add type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname" displayName="Surname" value="Adams" />
      <add type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" displayName="Role" value="Member" />
      <add type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" displayName="Email" value="terry@contoso.com" />
      <add type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier" displayName="Name Identifier" value="terry@contoso.com" />
    </claims>
  </localSTSConfiguration>
</configuration>
```

The above will work without problem but if I want for the user to be a member of both the Member role and the Administrator role how do i express that. I have tried the following but it only includes the last of the specified claim values for a given claim type. The result is therefore that given the configuration below, the user will only be a member of the Administrator role, not the Member role.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    ...
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    ...
  </startup>
  <localSTSConfiguration port="13248" signingCertificate="LocalSTS.pfx" signingCertificatePassword="LocalSTS" issuerName="LocalSTS" tokenFormat="Saml11">
    <claims>
      ...
      <add type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" displayName="Role" value="Member" />
      <add type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" displayName="Role" value="Administrator" />
      ...
    </claims>
  </localSTSConfiguration>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that up until LocalSTS dll version 4 (included in Identity and Access Tool 1.01) multiple claim values are not a possibility but with LocalSTS dll version 5 (included in Identity and Access Tool 1.02) this ability has been added. Version 1.02 of the tools was released on the 23rd of october and can be found here http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e21bf653-dfe1-4d81-b3d3-795cb104066e?SRC=VSIDE.